# What is the best way to store collections in the local folder?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I've a simple app with a simple observable collection. User can manually add item to list by clicking add button and can give it a name and some other related properties.

I am trying to store those properties, for example let's say user add a new item with name "Sample" now when the app is terminated or user navigates to another page. The collection is reset with no items. So what is the best way to store value of each item and then restore it back when app loads or navigates to that page.

Note: User is given the right to add as many items as he wants and each items has total of eight(can vary) different properties.

Comment: Serialisation is probably what you are looking for

Comment: If you don't want to persist into a database, then serialize the data object as json and save to the file system.

Comment: a simple nosql database might be a good fit for you. Maybe have a look at Mongo which has a portable .exe you can launch at application start and then you can use one of the NuGet packages to interact with it directly using objects your are familiar with.
If you really want to save it to a folder as a flat file (e.g. text file) then I'd recommend using JSON since it's pretty light and easy to deal with. Newtonsoft.Json is probably the go to NuGet package for dealing with JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues here.

#### maintaining `ObservableCollection` when the user navigates to different view from current view.

To handle this, you can initialize your `ObservableCollection` globally once instead of in the page where you use it. Likely in App.xaml.cs

So if you have a `ObservableCollection<string>` that you use, Add this initialization in App.xaml.cs as

```
public ObservableCollection<string> GlobalList {get; set;} = new ObservableCollectin<string>;
```

Now in any view you can use `App` reference as like `App.GlobalList` to do Add,Remove and what other functions you want to use.

#### maintaining `ObservableCollection` when the user closes the app.

I strongly recommend [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). Simple, easy, fast and lightweight Json Parser to convert your ObservableCollection to Json and back.

You can convert Your `ObservableCollection` to `json` string like below.

```
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(App.GlobalList);
```

You can convert your `json` to `ObservableCollection` like below.

```
App.GlobalList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<string>>(jsonData);
```

you can save and retrieve the data using the methods below. ([GIST](https://gist.github.com/avknaidu/af3f5817f51e296644ebb22fe4aa6d49))

```
public async void SaveList(string FileName, string StringValue)
{
    StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    StorageFile sampleFile = (File.Exists(Path.Combine(storageFolder.Path,FileName))) ?
        await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName)
       :await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, StringValue);
}

public async Task<string> RetrieveList(string FileName)
{
    StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile sampleFile = (File.Exists(Path.Combine(storageFolder.Path,FileName))) ?
            await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName)
           : await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    return await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
}
```

So to Save your json, you need to call

```
SaveList("GlobalList.txt", jsonData);
```

and to retrieve you need to call

```
string jsonData = await RetrieveList("GlobalList.txt");
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Great answer, worked perfectly. But I am facing yet another issue. I've a StorageFolder in my CollectionList, and deserializer is throwing error. The error makes perfect sense but what do I do about it?

Comment: I'm facing one more problem, I am getting an error when defining my observable collection in app.xaml.cs and I guess I'm getting error because the collections holds instances of a class that's defined in a different file. If I try to make a collection of string it shows no error as in your example but when I use collection of a custom class it shows error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've sorted out the problems.

Comment: @JaiSharma sorry i did not see your previous comment. Glad you took care of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

store your data in a database 
or local file (xml - json .. or even txt files ) . 
and then load and update the data as you want .

**recommended**

use sql server database to store your data

Answer (score 0):

Store `ObservableCollection` using [Object Storage Helper](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/ObjectStorage/)

Here is a sample code

```
var helper = new LocalObjectStorageHelper();

// Save objects 
var o = new MyLargeObject
{
    ...
};
await helper.SaveFileAsync(keySimpleObject, o);

// Read objects 
string keyLargeObject = "large";
if (await helper.FileExistsAsync(keyLargeObject))
{
    var result = await helper.ReadFileAsync<MyLargeObject>(keyLargeObject);
}
```